# How do I import Microsoft Sticky Notes from Windows 7 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, import, sticky-notes

I know that Microsoft Sticky Notes are stored on Windows 10 in %AppData%\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe

I have a StickyNotes.snt file from my Windows 7 computer. How do I import it to Sticky Notes on Windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried putting the file in the same location?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. On your Windows 7 machine, navigate to the following folder:

   > %AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes
2. Save the **StickyNotes.snt** file found within to an external backup device.
3. On your Windows 10 machine, close all instances of Sticky Notes and open the following folder:

   > %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState
4. Create a new subfolder named **Legacy** within that folder.
5. Inside the *Legacy* folder, restore your *StickyNotes.snt* file and rename it **ThresholdNotes.snt**.
6. When you start the Sticky Notes app, your legacy content will be imported automatically:

   [image: Sticky Notes]

**Sources**:
[Windows 7: Sticky Notes - Backup and Restore](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/166067-sticky-notes-backup-restore.html)
[Microsoft Sticky Notes Importing Legacy Sticky Notes](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1a506139-79ec-45ae-82ab-b6b0d90abe0f/microsoft-sticky-notes-importing-legacy-sticky-notes?forum=win10itprogeneral)
[Backup and Restore Sticky Notes in Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/recover-backup-sticky-notes-data-file-windows-10/#convert)

Comment: i found this simple solution http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/9309/windows-7-how-to-import-and-export-sticky-notes/

Comment: Works very well. Imported notes from Windows-7 to Windows-10

Comment: I was not able to achieve this even after following the steps mentioned here. The problem was that I had already opened Sticky Notes one time. I had to close the app, reset it from `Settings --> Apps --> Sticky Notes --> Advanced Options --> Reset`. This will basically make the `LocalState` folder empty. Then I have copied `Threshold.snt` file in `Legacy` folder(created manually) & started app. It worked.

Comment: For me I didn't have `Advanced Options` (Windows 10 1903) -- But it worked by instead deleteing the files in the folder and only keeping the Legacy folder :)